# R Shiny & htmltools - Extracting a tag by name

Tags: r, shiny, htmltools

I have a `tagList` of two Shiny inputs, `inputs`. I would like to extract the `label` tag for each input. I was hoping that `htmltools` had a getter function to achieve this but in the absence of one I've defined a function, `getLabel`, that recurses through the input list and extracts the sublists whose name element equals the value `label`. Here is my code:

```
library(htmltools)
library(shiny)

inputs = tagList(
    selectInput('first', 'FIRST', letters), 
    checkboxInput(inputId = 'second', label = 'SECOND')
)

getLabel2 <- function(children) {

  lapply(children, function(x) {

    if(inherits(x, 'shiny.tag')) {

      if(x$name == 'label') {

        return(x)

      } else {

        chldn = x$children

        if(is.list(chldn)) getLabel2(chldn)

      }

    }

  })

}


getLabel <- function(inputs) {

  lapply(inputs, function(x) {

    if(grepl('shiny-input-container', tagGetAttribute(x, 'class'))) {

      getLabel2(x$children)

    } else {

      return(x)

    }

  })
}

labels = getLabel(inputs)
```

The problem is that the resulting list includes zero-length sublists. My desired output is a list of two elements (the label for each input) of class 'shiny-tag'. How can I modify my function to achieve this? Also, can this be done in `htmltools`? I can't find any relevant getters in the package manual.

Answer (score 1):

**You could do:**

```
inputs %>%
  toString %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//label") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  list
```

**Explanation:**

shiny inputs are basically html code. The same holds for `tagList()`. (You can check it by running `selectInput` or your variable `inputs` in your console,...). So you can use xpath/css to parse the resulting xml document.

There might be another way with htmltools, this just came to my mind when thinking about that shiny inputs are basically html code.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

inputs = tagList(
  selectInput('first', 'FIRST', letters), 
  checkboxInput(inputId = 'second', label = 'SECOND')
)

inputs %>% toString %>% read_html %>% 
   html_nodes(xpath = "//label") %>% html_text() %>% list
```

Comment: Thank you @BigDataScientist, this is a nice solution but unfortunately as specified in my post I require the output to be a list of two tags with class `shiny.tag`. So I need to preserve the structure of the label tags when extracting them. Is there a way to do this using a recursive function as in the post?

Comment: The function I've defined in my post nearly gets me there, except that the resulting list includes `NULL`s. I just need help tweaking that function so that it returns a list of length 2, where the first element is the label tag for input 1 and the second element is the label tag for input 2.

Comment: ah sry i missread that. Will take a look if i can modify your functions.

Comment: No problem, thanks for looking into it. I have still upvoted your solution.